# Creating html file based on template in java web application

Tags: java, html, web

I am creating a web application and upon user registration I would like to create a html file named by that username (i.e. joebloggs123 is username, therefore the html file is joebloggs123.html). I would like to use a template html file as it will cover basic profile content for the user when created.
So far I have the following:

```
File htmlTemplateFile = new File("/Convocast-war/web/userTemplate.html");
String htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(htmlTemplateFile);
String title = username + "'s Profile";
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$title", title);
File newHtmlFile = new File("/userPages/" + username + ".html");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile, htmlString);
System.out.println(newHtmlFile);
```

However I am getting filenotfoundexception on the htmlTemplateFile path.
Included is my directory structure but no matter the file path I use it will not find the file.
I have tried many other variations but nothing seems to find the file.
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C3Gb.png)

Comment: I strongly suggest not using the `File` class and related classes, and switching instead to using `Path` and `Files`. The `File` class is badly written, doesn't give good exceptions, and sometimes confuses between permission issues and "file not found". In your case, though, remember that you have to write the path relative to the file system, not the application tree. Is `Comvocast-war` directly under the / directory?

Comment: Are you talking about java.nio.file.path? The whole project /Convocast and the whole web application is /Convocast/Convocast-war/. I thought ../../web/userTemplate.html would be the relative filepath. I'll try using Path and see if this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to locate that file.

change your first line to:

```
File f = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/userTemplate.html"));
```

Comment: This found the file, although now it says it is creating a HTML file although I can't find it, even with the above code which makes me believe it's not creating at all.